# Adding JavaScript settimeout function

Tags: javascript, css, events, dom-events

I am not a coder/programmer and I found a script I would like to use and I used my wysiwyg editor to try to make it work the best I could, but it still does not work the way I want maybe someone could help me.

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
redirectTime = "5000";
redirectURL = "http://somesite.com";
function timedRedirect() {

setTimeout("location.href = redirectURL;",redirectTime);

}
//   -->
</script>

<textarea name="TextArea1" id="TextArea1" onblur="timedRedirect() ;return false;"    style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:390px;width:108px;height:108px;z-index:1;" rows="3" cols="9"></textarea>
```

With this this script I am trying to add an alert box to it, the script works (found it online), but when I try to add the alert to it triggers automatically not after the timer goes off. It should trigger the same time as the script. It show go alert box,  url redirect at specified `settimeout`.

If someone could help that would be great. I tried to script them to work to the best of my ability and was not able to. If someone could put an edited version of what I am trying to accomplish that would be great.

Comment: @UnLoCo No it doesn't. If it's a string, it evaluates it when the timeout occurs, if it's a function it calls it when the timeout occurs.

Comment: Show the code where you tried to add the alert, since that's where you're having trouble. I'm not sure what the point of showing the first script was, though -- if it's not relevant to the question, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var redirectTime = 5000;
var redirectURL = "http://somesite.com";

function doRedirect() {
    alert("We're about to redirect!");
    window.location.href = redirectURL;
}

function timedRedirect() {
    setTimeout(doRedirect, redirectTime);
}
```

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks, I forgot to wrap the `setTimeout` in the handler function.

Comment: Just realized is question is actually about where to place the alert.

Comment: @Yeah, he didn't write the question very well. I asked him to update it, but he never came back, so I just threw together what he's probably looking for.

Comment: @Barmar I had two questions that's why I had two different scripts. I think I will remove it and put it in separate question. What I am trying to do in the first script is settimeout for the mouse cursor focus in text box form instead of using onload

Comment: Yes, if you have two questions, post them separately. And try to make them clearer. Don't just post code and leave us to figure out what you're trying to do. Show the code that tries to do what you want.